# Wrong dimension received by Tensor Sequential model for 1D CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I load my dataset from Pandas dataframe and follow the instructions given by Tensorflow, but i modified it since i have my own train,validation and test dataset. This is my dataframe datatypes and I load it using tensorflow dataset (target is CLASS, RECORD_NAME and MINUTE are not included):

```
RECORD_NAME        int64
Minute             int64
ShanEn11         float64
DimFractal11     float64
Approx11         float64
                  ...   
DimFractal416    float64
Approx416        float64
SampEnt416       float64
D2416            float64
CLASS              int64
Length: 153, dtype: object
```

So i have 150 * 1 input dimension for my model here and use Binary since the class are 0 and 1:

```
def GetModel2():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=5,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=128,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=128,kernel_size=13,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=256,kernel_size=7,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(150,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

and this is the method how i convert my dataframe for train and validation into model:

```
def dataset_maker(train,valid):
    trainY = train.pop('CLASS')
    validY = valid.pop('CLASS')
    trainY = trainY.values
    validY = validY.values
    trainX = train.drop(columns=['Minute','RECORD_NAME']).values
    validX = valid.drop(columns=['Minute','RECORD_NAME']).values
    # trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX,axis=-1)
    # validX = np.expand_dims(validX,axis=-1)
    train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY))
    valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validX, validY))
    # return(trainX,validX,trainY,validY)
    return train,valid
```

for test:

```
def test_maker(test,nsr_time,sddb_time):
    test_sddb_sel = test[(test['CLASS']== 1) & (test['Minute']== sddb_time)]
    test_nsr_sel = test[(test['CLASS']== 0)].sample(n=len(test_sddb_sel))
    subs = [test_sddb_sel,test_nsr_sel]
    subs =  pd.concat(subs)
    testY  = subs.pop('CLASS').values
    subs=subs.drop(columns=['Minute','RECORD_NAME']).values
    test= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testX, testY))
    return(test)
```

But when i run this line:

```
 model = GetModel2()
 model.fit(train, epochs=500, validation_data = (valid))
```

This error happens:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (150, 1)
```

I though that my input are correct since i only have 1Dim dataset. Any help are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I will explain what i do in dataset maker. Before i build the dataset for train and validation, i need to set which group of data should used for. Since there is two csv contain record of each class (binary 1 and 0), it also contain information about the Record name and Minute. Each record has 30 minute so the structure should be

```
RECORD_NAME Minute  ShanEn11    DimFractal11    Approx11    SampEnt11   D211    ShanEn12    DimFractal12    Approx12    SampEnt12   D212    ShanEn21    DimFractal21    Approx21    SampEnt21   D221    ShanEn22    DimFractal22    Approx22    SampEnt22   D222    ShanEn23    DimFractal23    Approx23    SampEnt23   D223    ShanEn24    DimFractal24    Approx24    SampEnt24   D224    ShanEn31    DimFractal31    Approx31    SampEnt31   D231    ShanEn32    DimFractal32    Approx32    ... DimFractal49    Approx49    SampEnt49   D249    ShanEn410   DimFractal410   Approx410   SampEnt410  D2410   ShanEn411   DimFractal411   Approx411   SampEnt411  D2411   ShanEn412   DimFractal412   Approx412   SampEnt412  D2412   ShanEn413   DimFractal413   Approx413   SampEnt413  D2413   ShanEn414   DimFractal414   Approx414   SampEnt414  D2414   ShanEn415   DimFractal415   Approx415   SampEnt415  D2415   ShanEn416   DimFractal416   Approx416   SampEnt416  D2416   CLASS
0   16265   1   11.906891   0.381605    0.612757    0.373743    0.383648    11.906891   0.425259    1.577411    1.296275    0.603426    10.906891   0.388828    0.786206    0.539881    0.538828    10.906891   0.163120    0.849461    0.517985    0.490904    10.906891   0.465596    1.603956    1.578086    0.884919    10.906891   0.478893    1.489283    1.335001    0.795363    9.906891    0.443527    1.049104    1.026672    1.053325    9.906891    0.433486    0.845778    ... 0.494621    1.316569    2.000113    1.348125    8.906891    0.559719    1.377016    2.182452    1.356932    8.906891    0.555625    1.319638    2.039932    1.225024    8.906891    0.477939    1.315621    2.035342    1.395533    8.906891    0.441140    1.284476    1.874663    1.249584    8.906891    0.488296    1.320431    2.129360    1.424701    8.906891    0.355288    1.327155    1.933752    1.097245    8.906891    0.418731    1.313926    2.071668    1.383929    0
```

So i list each record and slice it into proportion 50:20:30 as train-test-validation. For class 0 it has 20 unique record name so the number of dimension for training for class 0 is 10 record*30 minutes each *150 row = 300*150 and for class  1 is 9*30*150 = 270*150.

and the process look like this:

```
    for w in range(n_exp):
        print('Sequence ',w+1)
        zeros,unos = shufling(zero,uno)
        zero_train,zero_val,zero_test = halfing_ZERO(zeros)
        print('ZERO_TRAIN_VALID_TEST = ',zero_train,zero_val,zero_test)
        uno_train,uno_val,uno_test = halfing_UNO(unos)
        print('UNO_TRAIN_VALID_TEST = ',uno_train,uno_val,uno_test)
        ZERO_tra = zero_data.loc[zero_data['RECORD_NAME'].isin(zero_train)]
        ZERO_val = zero_data.loc[zero_data['RECORD_NAME'].isin(zero_val)]
        ZERO_test = zero_data.loc[zero_data['RECORD_NAME'].isin(zero_test)]
        UNO_tra= norm_data.loc[norm_data['RECORD_NAME'].isin(uno_train)]
        UNO_val = norm_data.loc[norm_data['RECORD_NAME'].isin(uno_val)]
        UNO_test = norm_data.loc[norm_data['RECORD_NAME'].isin(uno_test)]
        train = [ZERO_tra,UNO_tra]
        valid = [ZERO_val,UNO_val]
        tests = [ZERO_test,UNO_test]
        train_dt = pd.concat(train)
        valid_dt = pd.concat(valid)
        test_dt = pd.concat(tests)
```

where zero and uno represent list of unique record name. The the dataset_maker are called to make train and valid test. Since the testing are quite tricky due i want to test the result for each minutes, the process to create test dataset are recursively done by get all data from record with certain minute label.

so from this process will produce train test and validation data with this same proportion and size:

```
train = (300*150) for class 1 and (270*150) for class 0 from 10 rec class 1 and 9 rec class 0
valid = (60*150) for class 1 and (60*150) for class 0 from 2 rec both on class 1 and 0
test = (240*150) for class 1 and (210*150) for class 0 from 8 rec class 1 and 7 class 1
```

Comment: What is a shape of train in model.fit(...)? or is it a tuple?

Comment: the shape is 150*1 since there are 150 feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow Conv1D expects input shape as `[batchsize, steps, input_dims]`, and outputs `[batchsize, new_steps, filters]`. Batchsize can be any integer, often depending on a machine memory. Then your batch will be ``[batchsize, 150, 1]```. That's why you got that error.

Now you use `model.fit`. model.fit expects params to be `x = tensor of [the num of total samples, 150, 1]`, `y=[the num of total samples, 1]`, and you specify batch_size also

[tf.keras.layers.Conv1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D)
[Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

add input_shape at the first layer.

```py
def GetModel2():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=5,activation='relu', input_shape=[150, 1]))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=128,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=128,kernel_size=13,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=256,kernel_size=7,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(150,activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Be careful about input shape.

```py
def dataset_maker(train,valid):
    trainY = train.pop('CLASS')
    validY = valid.pop('CLASS')
    trainY = trainY.values  # [750,1]
    validY = validY.values  # [?, 1]
    trainX = train.drop(columns=['Minute','RECORD_NAME']).values
    validX = valid.drop(columns=['Minute','RECORD_NAME']).values

    trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX,axis=-1)  # [750, 150] -> [750, 150, 1]
    validX = np.expand_dims(validX,axis=-1)  # [?, 150] -> [?, 150, 1]
    train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY))
    valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validX, validY))
    # return(trainX,validX,trainY,validY)
    return train,valid
```

```py
 # Make sure you have right shapes. trainX: [750, 150, 1], trainY: [750, 1]
 batch_size=750
 model = GetModel2()
 model.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY, epochs=500, validation_data=(validX, validY), batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: i don't want to use batch since my data for training are pretty small (570 row). So should i declare the number of batch manually on the model or declare it when made the dataset by expand the dimension of tensor dataset?

Comment: If you don't specify batchsize in mode.fit, it defaults to 32 as in doc >Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.
So I recommend you to set [750, 150, 1] as input shape and set params as ```mode.fit(..., batch_size=750)```.

Comment: i have try to put the batch size like this
```model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=hp.get('feature size'),kernel_size=hp.get('windows size'),activation='relu',input_shape = (750,150,1)))``` but still the error occured

Comment: ```model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=hp.get('feature size'),kernel_size=hp.get('windows size'),activation='relu',input_shape = (150,1)))``` is fine. You have to specify ```batch_size``` in ```model.fit```
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D

Comment: still the same, the error always occuring.
```model.fit(train, batch_size=750, epochs=500, validation_data = (valid))```

Comment: Make sure train.shape is [750, 150, 1] in mode.fit

Comment: i check the slice of the train shape
it was returned like this
```<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((150,), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.int64)>``` which is missing the 1 dimension on it

Comment: when i try to change the input size like this ```input_size=(150,)``` the error change into ```Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 150)```

Comment: I'm not sure how you use dataset_maker, but I updated my answer.

Comment: I have update the flow to use my dataset_maker function